# LINQ statement broke after upgrading to .NET Core 1.1 Preview 1

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core application that tracks work crews. `WorkCrewMembers` is the class that contains crew members. It has a key into `WorkCrew` class that has a somewhat clumsy list of `TimeSpan?` fields specifying when this crew starts working on specific days of the week: `SunStart, MonStart, TueStart, WedStart, ThuStart, FriStart, SatStart`. The classes are generated from legacy database. I have the following code that was working happily in ASP.NET Core 1.0.1

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DBContext context = new DBContext()) {
            var lstWorkCrew = (from m in context.WorkCrewMembers
                where m.WorkCrew.TodayStartTime() != null
                select m.WorkCrewId).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine($"Today {lstWorkCrew.Count} work crews");
        }
    }
}

public partial class WorkCrew {
    public TimeSpan? TodayStartTime() {
        TimeSpan?[] starts = {
            SunStart, MonStart, TueStart, WedStart, ThuStart, FriStart, SatStart
        };
        int dayOfWeek = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        return starts[dayOfWeek];
    }
}
```

However, when I upgraded the packages to [1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/), I am getting the following error in the line with `m.WorkCrew.TodayStartTime()`:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Method 'System.Nullable`1[System.TimeSpan] TodayStartTime()' declared on type 'WorkCrew' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Int32'

Interesting that if I do `from w in context.WorkCrew where w.TodayStartTime() != null select w` it works fine.

Is it a breaking change in 1.1? Or it is something that should throw an exception earlier because my code is not legit? Or simply a bug that Microsoft will fix?

Answer (score 1):

It appears really that the order of `Select` and `Where` were somehow inverted in this LINQ notation and you got the select first that returned you an Id. That explains why it works if you select the item itself and not the Id.

I think if you change it to

```
context.WorkCrewMembers
       .Where(m => m.WorkCrew.TodayStartTime() != null)
       .Select(m => m.WorkCrewId)
       .ToList();
```

it will work properly.

I personally prefer this notation :)

Comment: Alas! Got exactly the same error :( It seems that for some reason `m.WorkCrew` is now null! If I first get `var wcm = context.WorkCrewMembers.ToList()`, and then have `wcm.Where(m => m.WorkCrew?.TodayStartTime())` - I don't get an exception, but I get 0 rows back, as if *all* `m.WorkCrew` are null

Comment: Sorry, this seems like a bug really, I can't see how this simple snippet can produce this type of error. It should not even be able to compile in case something is wrong in here. I suppose you don't do some hidden reflection calls somewhere inside your classes.

Comment: I can't believe there is something wrong with LINQ in general here, might happen that the LINQ to EF here does some nasty tricks,  you can try to see which SQL is executed as well. I am unfortunately not an expert on EF at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turns out amazingly simple:
Instead of `where m.WorkCrew.TodayStartTime() != null` in ASP.NET Core 1.1 you should use `where m.WorkCrew.TodayStartTime != null`